# realm on sdk 16(Jelly Bean) without rxjava crashing

Tags: android, realm

Important details

I have added the dummy class listed here
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind

And everything works well on Lollipop but as soon as I created a Genymotion emulator for 4.1 Jelly Bean and try to push the application I get the errors listed below which looks like it is trying to resolve the OnSubscribe interface defined within rxjava Observable which I am dummying.

I was not using Proguard for the below stack, but after setting it up I am getting the same.

**Is this expected and should be ignored?**  I have one or two other warn messages I am trying to track down as well.

> 03-03 16:55:58.510 2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android I/dalvikvm:
>   Failed resolving Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4; interface
>   7525 'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;'
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   Link of class    'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4;' failed
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class    'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$4',
>   referenced from method
>   io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.getObjectObservable
>
> 03-03    16:55:58.510 2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY:    unable to resolve new-instance 6678
>   (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory;
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode    0x22 at 0x0000
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510 2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android    I/dalvikvm:
>   Failed resolving Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3;    interface
>   7525 'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;'
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   Link of class    'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3;' failed
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class    'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$3',
>   referenced from method
>   io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.getRealmResultsObservable
>
> 03-03    16:55:58.510 2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY:    unable to resolve new-instance 6675
>   (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory;
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode    0x22 at 0x0000
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510 2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android    I/dalvikvm:
>   Failed resolving Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2;    interface
>   7525 'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;'
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   Link of class    'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2;' failed
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class    'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$2',
>   referenced from method    io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.from
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve    new-instance 6672
>   (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory;
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode    0x22 at 0x0003
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510 2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android    I/dalvikvm:
>   Failed resolving Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1;    interface
>   7525 'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;'
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   Link of class    'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1;' failed
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class    'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$1',
>   referenced from method    io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.from
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve    new-instance 6669
>   (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory;
>
> 03-03 16:55:58.510    2017-2017/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode    0x22 at 0x0003

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this was not what was causing the Application to crash, it was just one of the many error messages being logged when running on dalvik instead of Art.

The issue I encountered was trying to run an app that was using Google Services on a version before 4.2.2 as instructed here.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

"The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher."

So I still see the following error when deploying but the app seems to be functioning correctly.

> 03-03 15:51:20.063 16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android I/dalvikvm:
>   Failed resolving Lio/realm/a/a$1; interface 5529
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-03 15:51:20.063
>   16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/a/a$1;' failed 03-03 15:51:20.063
>   16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'io.realm.a.a$1', referenced from method io.realm.a.a.a 03-03
>   15:51:20.063 16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve new-instance 4885 (Lio/realm/a/a$1;) in
>   Lio/realm/a/a; 03-03 15:51:20.063 16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000 03-03 15:51:20.063
>   16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/a/a$1; interface 5529 'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-03
>   15:51:20.063 16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android W/dalvikvm: Link of
>   class 'Lio/realm/a/a$1;' failed 03-03 15:51:20.063
>   16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0x8e17 at 0x02 in Lio/realm/a/a;.a 03-03 15:51:20.063
>   16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.armssoftware.android-1/librealm-jni.so 0xa63d1538
>   03-03 15:51:20.063 16882-16921/com.armssoftware.android D/dalvikvm:
>   Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.armssoftware.android-1/librealm-jni.so 0xa63d1538

Comment: Glad to know Realm is not the cause of the crash. We are working on removing those RxJava related warning message in this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2361 . Also we are trying to figure out a way to totally remove the RxJava related interface if user doesn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

In Realm documentation, specific [section](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind) about Jackson say that the solucion is adding RxJAVA dependency in your project.
In my personal case, it's worked.